# Start god process on server startup (Ubuntu)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu-12.04, god, process-monitoring

I'm currently struggling with executing a simple command which I know works when I run it manually when logged in as either root or non-root user:

```
god -c path/to/app/queue_worker.god
```

I'm trying to run this when the server starts (I'm running Ubuntu 12.04), and I've investigated adding it to `/etc/rc.local` just to see if it runs. I know I can add it to `/etc/init.d` and then use update-rc.d but as far as I understand it's basically the same thing.

My question is how I run this command after everything has booted up as clean as possible without any fuzz.

Im probably missing something in the lifecycle of how everything's initialized, but then I gladly encourage some education! Are there alternative ways or places of putting this command?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could write a bash script to determine when Apache has started and then set it to run as a cron job at a set interval...

```
if [ "$(pidof apache)" ] 
then
  # process was found
else
  # process not found
fi
```

Of course then you'll have a useless cron job running all the time, and you'll have to somehow flip a switch once it's run once so it doesn't run again.. This should give you an idea to start from..

Comment: That's an alternative yes. But sounds like I'm doing monitoring of the process then, and then I can use Ubuntu's Upstart or something similar. Basically what "god" does it monitoring processes, but I just want to kickstart it when Ubuntu starts up so it starts monitoring and is reboot-insensitive.